# In django : how to renew expiry date for current session?

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I have a user logged in.
How can i extend/renew expiry date of session received from the request ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In renew I want to set the expiry date of the session to 15 days from current time.

Answer (score 9):

It's not necessary to make a custom middleware for this.

Setting `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True` will cause Django's existing `SessionMiddleware` to do exactly what you want.

It has this code:

```
if modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST:
    if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
        max_age = None
        expires = None
    else:
        max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
        expires_time = time.time() + max_age
        expires = cookie_date(expires_time)
    # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
    # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
    if response.status_code != 500:
        request.session.save()
        response.set_cookie(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
                request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None)
```

Comment: I think this might not scale due to db update required for every request for every user  Maybe redis?

Comment: @java-addict301 I agree, for that purpose I would happily recommend https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis#configure-as-session-backend

Answer (score 7):

Here's some middleware that extends an authenticated user's session. It essentially keeps them permanently logged in by extending their session another 60 days if their session `expiry_date` is less than 30 days away.

**custom_middleware.py:**

```
from datetime import timedelta

from django.utils import timezone


EXTENDED_SESSION_DAYS = 60
EXPIRE_THRESHOLD = 30
class ExtendUserSession(object):
    """
    Extend authenticated user's sessions so they don't have to log back in
    every 2 weeks (set by Django's default `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` setting). 
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        # Only extend the session for auth'd users
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            now = timezone.now()

            # Only extend the session if the current expiry_date is less than 30 days from now
            if request.session.get_expiry_date() < now + timedelta(days=EXPIRE_THRESHOLD):
                request.session.set_expiry(now + timedelta(days=EXTENDED_SESSION_DAYS))
```

You will then need to add this custom middleware *after* Django's SessionMiddleware, so your settings file should look like:

**project/settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'project.custom_middleware.ExtendUserSession',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Does this *definitely* work as advertised? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_date) for `get_expiry_date` say "this will equal the date `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` seconds from **now**" (emphasis mine), which is consistent with my local testing.

Comment: `get_expiry_date()` to me always returns the current time plus the expirary age.

Answer (score 2):

setting [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age) is designed for that purpose I believe. After login cookie is set automatically for this period.

You can also save session cookie on every request by using [SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-save-every-request) setting.

Comment: yeah.. but if user's session is about to expire and I want to extend his session's expiry date further, then is there a way ?