# Django session expires at browser close OR after time

Tags: django, session, session-cookies

The Django documentation states:

> You can control whether the session framework uses browser-length
>   sessions vs. persistent sessions with the
>   SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting.
>
> If SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE is set to True, Django will use
>   browser-length cookies -- cookies that expire as soon as the user
>   closes his or her browser. Use this if you want people to have to log
>   in every time they open a browser.
>
> This setting is a global default and can be overwritten at a
>   per-session level by explicitly calling the set_expiry() method of
>   request.session as described above in using sessions in views.

So when I set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE to True in my settings file, this indeed is what it does. This is good because I want a user's session to expire upon browser close. However, I also want a user's session to expire after, say, 15 minutes of inactivity. If I use set_expiry() mentioned above, the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE is overridden so if a user closes the browser and then re-opens the browser before the expiration, the session is still valid.  Not what I want.

In addition, the documentation for set_expiry() says the sessions expires after the set amount of time of ***inactivity***. That's actually not true. It expires no matter what, whether my user is clicking around on the site or not.

So to summarize, what I want to do is:

1. Have my sessions configured that if the user closes the browser, the session automatically expires.
2. Set a session expiration length that is updated with activity, i.e. if a user does something else on the site, the expiration is reset.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: test this after closing your browser not only tab

Comment: This may be what you were after. http://django-session-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jiaaro suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024153/how-to-expire-session-due-to-inactivity-in-django) you can use `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` and set a timestamp on session at each request and add a custom `Middleware` to handle the inactivity.

Comment: It doesn't work with Chrome v23 (at least on Ubuntu 12.04)  **Note**: `Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting ...` source: [browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions)

Comment: I maybe wrong however some reading shows that expire at browser close is not equivalent to expire at window close

Answer (score 0):

From docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions

> Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions expire when the user closes the browser:

> This requirement implemented by setting **SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE** to **True**.
>
> [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3024153/3702377)

Sessions expire after a period of inactivity:

> **SESSION_COOKIE_AGE** is the age of session cookies, in seconds.
>   Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
>
> [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)

You should set these option on your `setting/__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

Search engine cache make sure then the session will be closed when **TOGETHER** with `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = TRUE`

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, **SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE** is set to False, which means session cookies will be stored in users’ browsers for as long as **SESSION_COOKIE_AGE**. Use this if you don’t want people to have to log in every time they open a browser.

If **SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE** is set to True, Django will use browser-length cookies – cookies that expire as soon as the user closes their browser. Use this if you want people to have to log in every time they open a browser.