# How to handle Django sessions properly

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-cache

I have the following requirements:

1. Users must be able to see (and log out) their other sessions.
2. Sessions must expire *BOTH* at browser close and after a perioid of inactivity.
3. `default` database can not be used to store sessions.

My current approach would be to set `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` and add a [middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025372/180174) class that checks the last_activity / and updates the timestamp (or calls `logout()` if the session has expired) and also run a periodic cleanup on inactive sessions.

However, I couldn't find a way to access the non-database backed sessions outside a request (- or a way to access anything except the current session inside a request)
Furthermore, I couldn't find any documentation how to store the `django_session` table to another database.

I'm currently using cache backed sessions using a file based cache, but that can be changed - the only requirement is not to store the sessions in the `default` database.

Answer (score 1):

1) For this to find all sessions of current user - `request.user` - you will have to iterate through all session objects decode data and check the user id. Not very optimized. Something like:

May be you can optimize to iterate over non-expired sessions.

```
for s in Session.objects.all():
    data = s.get_decoded()
    if data['_auth_user_id'] == request.user.id:
        # you got session for current user
```

2) For this you need to manipulate session expiry data in custom middleware as you described.

3) To store session in different DB, you need to add [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing).

Something like :

```
class SessionRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations 
    sessions.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        if model == Session or model == SessionStore
            return 'session_db'
        return None
        #similar more methods
```

And in settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'session_db': {
        #settings for session db
    },
    #any other databases.
```

Comment: It seems that writing something that does what I need and use that instead of sessions seems like the most viable option - `~/git/django/django/contrib/sessions $ find . -name '*.py' |xargs cat|wc -l` says `1600` ...

Comment: @Kimvais, you can write your own middleware. But I think for #1 you need to do that in some view, based on user action.