# How to set session not to expire on browser close in django?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

How to set the session not to expire on browser close in Django?

I created cookie with expiry days:

In `setting.py` I added `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False` and
`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1440 * 60`.

When I logged in, cookies are created, but the attribute `Expires` for the cookie is "When the browsing session ends and `sessionid` cookies expires on (1 day time) 24 hours".

When I close the tab and reopen it, it keeps session continuous, but when I close the browser and reopen it, the cookies are also deleted, even `sessionid`. So it redirects to the login page again.

I want to keep session continuous even after reopening the browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024153/how-to-expire-session-due-to-inactivity-in-django have you checked this.

Comment: Also try not using the SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1440 * 60 only use SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False . Mention the django version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        request.session.set_expiry(settings.LOGIN_SESSION_TIMEOUT) 
        settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE =  False      
    return auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwargs)
```